# xamarin for windows mobile and desktop

Tags: xamarin

We are willing to create a new application that runs almost everywhere,

iOS, Android OSX and windows

We have sucesfully created samples for iOS, Android and OSX however we have the doubt of windows phone and windows desktop,
is it possible to have the same interface code for them both? or do we need to create the mobile and desktop version as well as in iOS and OSX?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just like creating the iOS and Android Projects, you will need to create separate projects for Windows Phone and Windows Desktop.